# Optimize a NULL / NOT NULL flags PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get one record that contains boolean flags: true if a column in specific result set has at least one NOT NULL value and false if all the values are NULL.

Sample data of a result set

```
SELECT "my column 1", "my column 2", "my column 3", "my column 4", "my column 5" 
FROM my_data 
WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end

"my column 1" "my column 2" "my column 3" "my column 4" "my column 5"
   NULL          NULL          25.2          NULL          1.12
   15.28         NULL          NULL          NULL          2.25
   NULL          NULL          13.9          NULL          3.03
   359.00        NULL          125.5         NULL          4.15
   NULL          NULL          152.2         NULL          5.99
   NULL          NULL          NULL          NULL          6.35
```

In this case result should be:

```
"my column 1" "my column 2" "my column 3" "my column 4" "my column 5"
   t             f             t             f             t
```

A following PostgreSQL query does exactly what I need (actually it terminates each subquery as soon as first NOT NULL value has been detected), but could it be be optimized?:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT * FROM my_data WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end)

SELECT
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM x WHERE "my column 1" IS NOT NULL) AS "my column 1",
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM x WHERE "my column 2" IS NOT NULL) AS "my column 2",
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM x WHERE "my column 3" IS NOT NULL) AS "my column 3",
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM x WHERE "my column 4" IS NOT NULL) AS "my column 4",
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM x WHERE "my column 5" IS NOT NULL) AS "my column 5"
```

I thought it could be written either shorter or universally, without mentioning each column name.

Comment: is it hitting performance ?

Comment: You can using CASE? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: @Ranadip Dutta: No, but I thought it could be written either shorter or universally, without mentioning each column name.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should _really_ avoid quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run then they are worth it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another alternative is to use the `bool_or()` aggregate which returns true if at lease one value is true.

```
SELECT bool_or("my column 1" is not null) AS "my column 1",
       bool_or("my column 2" is not null) AS "my column 2",
       bool_or("my column 3" is not null) AS "my column 3",
       bool_or("my column 4" is not null) AS "my column 4",
       bool_or("my column 5" is not null) AS "my column 5"
FROM my_data
WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end;
```

There is also the `bool_and()` aggregate that would return true only if all values are true.

Comment: Well, `bool_or` seems to be optimized. Its name promises that it stops aggregating when the first `true` value is found. May be it is not so.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
   count("my column 1") > 0 AS "my column 1",
   count("my column 2") > 0 AS "my column 2",
   count("my column 3") > 0 AS "my column 3",
   count("my column 4") > 0 AS "my column 4",
   count("my column 5") > 0 AS "my column 5"
FROM my_data
WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end;
```

Answer (score 1):

this return 1 for not null columns:

```
CASE WHEN "my column 1" IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

This add the number of not null columns:

```
COUNT( <previous case> ) > 0
```

Final query:

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN "my column 1" IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) > 0
           THEN true
           ELSE false
       END, 
       -- ..... same for the other columns
       -- , "my column 2", "my column 3", "my column 4", "my column 5" 
FROM my_data 
WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I just saw Laurenz answer. :$